# What does a field describe in Quantum Field Theory? What does a linear combination of (vectorial) fields mean?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I started studying QFT, and I’m very confused:
I thought a field was a way to describe a particle. When I started reading about Cassimir operators they defined the contraction $\partial_\mu\partial^\mu=p_\mu p^\mu =m^2$, I thought it defined the square of the mass of the field, however, the lagrangian for a free massive particle do need an extra term for the mass:
$L =\frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu\phi –\frac{1}{2} m^2\phi^2 $. Then I got confused.

Now, talking about representations, you have generators that depend on the basis. If I have a vectorial field that is a basis for the representation, then it means that any linear combinations are elements of the vector space, but what does it mean if I have those linear combinations? Does the coefficients of that linear combination have any interpretation?

Comment: Who is "they" in the phrase "they defined the contraction $\partial_\mu\partial^\mu=p_\mu p^\mu=m^2$"? Can you give some context around that result?

Comment: What does *"a vectorial field that is a basis for the representation"* mean? What reprensentation of what group? Linear combinations of *what* are you talking about?

Comment: @probably_someone Sorry, I read it in the book \textit{A Modern Introduction to Quantum Field Theory} by Michael Maggiore, i was wrong because the book does not define it as the mass, it is just mentioned that the value of that contraction is m^2. I'm currently reading on internet and perhaps the $m^2$ is the eigenvalue of some equation, but it isn't indicated. I imagine the eigenvalue equation is the Euler Lagrange equation for the Lagrangian I wrote above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it simply, a quantum field is just a combination of creation and annihilation operators that has simple commutation/anticommutation relations and transforms "nicely" under the Lorentz and other symmetry groups.

Starting from particles, one can define creation and annihilation operators. These operators satisfy certain commutation (or anticommutation) relations and, depending on the particle's spin, transform in "complicated" ways under Lorentz transformations.

On the other hand, it can be shown that the Hamiltonian (and Lagrangian) of the theory must be given in terms of creation and annihilation operators. Conditions for a physical theory put certain restrictions on the structure of the Hamiltonian (and Lagrangian) density, e.g. the Lagrangian density has to be a Lorentz scalar, Hamiltonian density at spacelike separations commute, etc. To have the Hamiltonian written in terms of creation and annihilation operators while satisfying all those restrictions, one can start by putting the creation and annihilation operators in a specific combination that has simple commutation relations and nice transformation properties. That is the motivation for quantum fields. The Halmitonian and Lagrangian density can be be constructed easily in terms of quantum fields.

That is Weinberg's viewpoint. A single quantum field, or similarly a linear combination of fields, is nothing more than just an operator-valued function (or distribution) arranged in a specific way that its transformations under various symmetry groups are manifestly clear.

Answer (score -2):

Quantum field theorists seem to me to be among the most ardent supporters of "shut-up and calculate". When pressed, they will usually say something like "physics is just algorithms to produce experimental results" and suggest that it is naive to suppose that human understanding is possible.

I was never able to accept that approach, and for this reason I am much more attracted to the original development of qed, by Dirac and others, as relativistic quantum mechanics. In this case, quantum fields are operators on Fock space used in the description of particle interactions. Certainly there were mathematical problems in Dirac's development, but quantum field theory only really seeks to sweep those problems under the carpet and pretend that they don't exist, just so long as you follow the algorithms. I thought it better to go back to square one, and reconstruct relativistic quantum mechanics paying extreme care to mathematical rigour. I did this in [A Construction of Full QED Using Finite Dimensional Hilbert Space](http://www.ejtp.com/articles/ejtpv10i28p27.pdf).

Comment: wadr, I have never in my life met a QFT who would say or live by "shut up and calculate".  Granted, if you work at Fermi lab they need calculations but every one of my advisors could eloquently describe the fundamental characteristics of QFT from first principles.

Comment: From 2.3: "Postulate:A particle is any physical entity whose position can be measured at given time".
From Davydov QM sec 53: "The idea of a single particle can thus only be retained if there are no external influences leading to the localisation of the particle in a volume with linear dimensions less than the Compton wave-length, $\hbar/mc$, of the particle. For ultra-relativistic particles - such as light quanta for which $m = 0, v = c$  - the concept of the coordinates of the particle in the usual sense of the word is completely meaningless." Your most basic definition excludes all of QFT.

Comment: There is no change to empirical results, only to interpretation. I do not claim to rigorously define QFT, only to show qed as relativistic quantum mechanics. It is already true in standard qm that particles do not have coordinates in the general case. The measurement of position generates the property of position.

Comment: In any event, that definition is only a starting point applicable to electrons. I stopped using it in later work. Nowhere do I treat particles as having coordinates in the classical sense.

Comment: From the same Davydov paragraph: "Non-relativistic quantum mechanics makes it possible to localise arbitrarily accurately a particle in space and time." In other words, particles do indeed have coordinates in the general case in non-relativistic QM, the problem is being able to specify that particles follow paths, which requires more than just coordinates - one can measure the coordinates at successive instants of time and what experiments show are of measurements that in no way allow one to say the particle followed a path, though the coordinates are arbitrarily accurate in principle.

Comment: It is possible to localise particles in measurement, not in the general case. Position is an observable. Dirac is a better authority, if you must have one. He said “In the general case we cannot speak of an observable having a value for a particular state, but we can … speak of the probability of its having a specified value for the state, meaning the probability of this specified value being obtained when one makes a measurement of the observable.” This applies to position as much as any other observable.